# Dynamic replacement of Spark dataframe columns per row

Tags: json, dataframe, apache-spark

I have here 2 JSON strings per record.

The first JSON string is variable, indicating column(s) to be replaced in second JSON string.

E.g. the input.

```
import spark.implicits._
// Leaving timestamp aspect out and multiple occurrence of changes in same run, for simplicity.
val df = Seq((1, """{"b": "new", "c": "new"}""",  """{"k": 1, "b": "old", "c": "old", "d": "old"}""" ),
             (2, """{"b": "new", "d": "new"}""",  """{"k": 2, "b": "old", "c": "old", "d": "old"}""" )).toDF("id", "chg", "before")
```

Like so:

```
+---+------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|id |chg                     |before                                      |
+---+------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|1  |{"b": "new", "c": "new"}|{"k": 1, "b": "old", "c": "old", "d": "old"}|
|2  |{"b": "new", "d": "new"}|{"k": 2, "b": "old", "c": "old", "d": "old"}|
+---+------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

What I want is - but I cannot get it completed - is this output, thus on a per row basis".

```
+---+--------------------------------------------+
|id |after                                       |
+---+------------------------+-------------------+
|1  |{"k": 1, "b": "new", "c": "new", "d": "old"}|
|2  |{"k": 2, "b": "new", "c": "old", "d": "new"}|
+---+------------------------+-------------------+
```

We could have an array in the JSON, that's fine as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go the strongly typed route, which gives you a lot of control over the exact transformations you want to have occur.

I made the following assumptions:

- your `before` column contains all of the fields in each row
- the `chg` column never contains the `k` field.

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders

// Creating case classes with the schema of your json objects. We're making
// these to make use of strongly typed Datasets. Notice that the MyChgClass has
// each field as an Option: this will enable us to choose between "chg" and
// "before"
case class MyChgClass(b: Option[String], c: Option[String], d: Option[String])
case class MyFullClass(k: Int, b: String, c: String, d: String)
case class MyEndClass(id: Int, after: MyFullClass)

// Creating schemas for the from_json function
val chgSchema = Encoders.product[MyChgClass].schema
val beforeSchema = Encoders.product[MyFullClass].schema

// Your dataframe from the example
val df = Seq(
  (1, """{"b": "new", "c": "new"}""",  """{"k": 1, "b": "old", "c": "old", "d": "old"}""" ),
  (2, """{"b": "new", "d": "new"}""",  """{"k": 2, "b": "old", "c": "old", "d": "old"}""" )
).toDF("id", "chg", "before")

// Parsing the json string into our case classes and finishing by creating a
// strongly typed dataset with the .as[] method
val parsedDf = df
  .withColumn("parsedChg",from_json(col("chg"), chgSchema))
  .withColumn("parsedBefore",from_json(col("before"), beforeSchema))
  .drop("chg")
  .drop("before")
  .as[(Int, MyChgClass, MyFullClass)]

// Mapping over our dataset with a lot of control of exactly what we want. Since
// the "chg" fields are options, we can use the getOrElse method to choose
// between either the "chg" field or the "before" field
val output = parsedDf.map{
  case (id, chg, before) => {
    MyEndClass(id, MyFullClass(
      before.k,
      chg.b.getOrElse(before.b),
      chg.c.getOrElse(before.c),
      chg.d.getOrElse(before.d)
    ))
  }
}

output.show(false)
+---+------------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
|id |after             |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
+---+------------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
|1  |[1, new, new, old]|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
|2  |[2, new, old, new]|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
+---+------------------+
```

So there you have it, the `output` dataset contains the values you want. Since you asked for it, we can turn it into a json string again (Opinion incoming: this is less useful within Spark IMO, so unless you absolutely need to output this json somewhere I would not do this) by doing the following:

```
output.select($"id", to_json($"after")).show(false)
+---+-------------------------------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|id |structstojson(after)                 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
+---+-------------------------------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|1  |{"k":1,"b":"new","c":"new","d":"old"}|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|2  |{"k":2,"b":"new","c":"old","d":"new"}|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
+---+-------------------------------------
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting. Thx. Work for tonight.

Comment: Impressed. For sure.